# Computing real world distance using pixel distance

Tags: computer-vision, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I have two images as [here a vehicle entered the region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS9ji.jpg) and other image as [here vehicle exited the region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyY1d.jpg)

I captured this images using a single CCTV camera mounted on a road.

Now I want to compute the real world distance travelled by it to find the speed of the vehicle. I use object detection to get the bounding boxes for car number plate in both the images there by I can compute pixel distance. I can map pixel distance to real world only when image plane and road plane are parallel to each other(I am using this technique but it isn't giving accurate results). Since my camera is inclined at an angle to the road, I couldn't use that technique.

I have tried few research papers but couldn't find any useful information relevant to my problem. Someone please share insights on doing it, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In this problem we have single camera view so there is not way you can find the real world distance between the objects using camera view geometry. Though we can convert the image pixels to real world unit by considering certain reference objects with known length values in real world units.

In the sample image captured you can identify the road lane markers as shown below in the image and knowing their lengths in real world units you can find the pixels to real world distance.

Below is a quick and basic implementation of road-lane marker detection approach. This will also give you contours in the objects like car, bike in the image but you can remove such contours by applying mask over those objects once you know their object bounding boxes.

```
img = cv2.imread("road_lane.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3))
# Find Canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(blur, 30, 200)

# Finding Contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
boundRect = []
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    #ignore large and small contours
    if len(c) < 300 and len(c) > 100 :
        box = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        #check for vertical rectangles
        if box[2] < box[3]:
           boundRect.append(box)

for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    cv2.rectangle(img, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), (255, 0, 0), 5)
```

[image]